# How to change the color of each column in a SharePoint chart?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, lookup-column, chart-web-part

How does one change the color of each column in a SharePoint Chart Web part? For example the "passed" column would be green, the "stopped" would be red.

I am pulling data from this list:

[image]

[image]

It seems like something very simple but I can not figure it out... Any suggestions?

Comment: check this one may help https://support.office.com/en-SG/Article/Create-a-chart-by-using-the-Chart-Web-Part-d781ed6d-cbdd-4da9-a5bf-cf346c98db72

Comment: Also check under the advance properties...http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2010/02/24/impress-the-boss-with-the-sharepoint-2010-chart-web-part.aspx

Comment: thanks for the links. unfortunately neither addresses changing column colors

Answer (score 1):

What i checked and looks like the chart web part does not have any settings to change the color of individual data points or plot data points of a series in different colors.

As a workaround check this [Change colors of bars in Chart Web part](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/5b535e69-52cb-4fc0-b8cb-1917ec4109fe/change-colors-of-bars-in-chart-web-part?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious) and refer below some content extracted from the link given.

The quickest way to do this, if the Web Part Configuration doesn't allow you do set the colours is to use CSS.

1. In your browser use a Developer Extension to identify the CSS classes you need to change.  IE has Developer Toolbar, FireFox has Web Developer, I'm not sure what Chrome uses
2. Write some CSS to override the settings
3. Apply it either via loading a Custom CSS in the Site Assets library or inline via CEWB